# Can I still start a "stable" D8 project now that D9 is stable?

Tags: 8, composer

Trying to start a new Drupal 8 project today:

```
$ composer create-project --no-install drupal/recommended-project my-recommended-project
```

But this now installs Drupal 9.0.0 instead! :mindblown:

So I tried to manually require 8.9:

```
$ composer create-project --no-install drupal/recommended-project^8.9 my-recommended-project
```

But:

```
Could not find package drupal/recommended-project^8.9 with stability stable.
```

So it seems like I will need to install `^8.9@dev`

But then the whole project will be ... unstable?

What do you recommend?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a `:`

This works:
`composer create-project --no-install drupal/recommended-project:^8.9 my-recommended-project`

Comment: That was quick! You are correct, it was just an obvious typo. I'll leave this here in case it helps anybody else!